# why getting wrong answer when using Collections.binarySearch()

Tags: java, collections

```
public class BinarySearchCollections {
  public static void search(List<String> list) {
    list.clear();
    list.add("b");
    list.add("a");
    list.add("c");
    System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(list, "b"));
    System.out.println(list);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> lis = new ArrayList<String>();
    BinarySearchCollections bs = new BinarySearchCollections();
    bs.search(lis);
  }
}
```

Here I am getting ans as -3 (as it is telling me at what location it is going to be added) but I already have b in my list.

Comment: @dlev that would be an answer, right

Comment: In general you are required to sort before performing a binary search in java.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart in general you are required to sort before performing a binary search in any platform, not just in java. "In computer science, a binary search or half-interval search algorithm finds the position of a specified value (the input "key") within a sorted array." [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original list isn't sorted, so binary search is going to give you a nonsense answer.

Imagine the steps it actually takes:

> "Is b > a? Yes, so look higher."
>
> "Is b > c? No, but we can't go lower, so insert at index 2 (aka return -3.)"

If you want binary search to work, give it a list on which it can take meaningful steps, and then give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.binarySearch()` does not ensure the list is sorted before attempting to search.  You need to make sure that is the case before calling `binarySearch()`.

If it did check the list first, it would turn a O(lg(n)) search into O(n+lg(n)) check/search, degrading performance. (O(nlg(n)) if it had to sort the list as well).

You should probably check out the [List.Sort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) method.